# Remove Bootstrap styling from controls/inputs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap includes some (very nice) styling for HTML inputs/selects/etc. However, for the project I'm on, they already have styling for these HTML elements that they want to keep.

Is there a way for me to turn off Bootstrap styles for inputs? Perhaps with some kind of css class? Or, do I have to override them manually?

Comment: You can either override them manually, or edit your bootstrap.css to not include the input styles.  Neither method is very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The order of inclusion of the stylesheets can help you.The inclusion of bootstrap.css followed by your own stylesheets makes elements in your stylesheet to override those in bootstrap.

For example,

```
<link href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link type=text/css rel='stylesheet' href=/static/main.css><!-- custom stylesheet -->
```

For eg,

If the `main.css` contains

```
body
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

And `bootstrapp.css` contains

```
body
{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

The site will be with a `red` background.